# insertAfter function - Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: jquery, dynamic

There are multiple elements **dynamically placed** with Javascript by a Wordpress plugin.

```
<div id="billing_address_1_field">address</div>
<div id="billing_country_field">country</div>
<div id="billing_postcode_field">postcode</div>
<div id="billing_city_field">city</div>
```

So I've added the following jQuery code to change the order of the elements:

```
(function($){

    $("body").bind("DOMNodeInserted", function() {

        //move before country fields
        $(this).find('#billing_postcode_field').insertBefore('#billing_country_field');
        $(this).find('#billing_city_field').insertBefore('#billing_country_field');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The postcode and city element should be before `#billing_country_field`.

When I go to that specific webpage, I get an unlimited loop of this error:
`Maximum call stack size exceeded error`

Expected result:

```
<div id="billing_address_1_field">address</div>
<div id="billing_postcode_field">postcode</div>
<div id="billing_city_field">city</div>
<div id="billing_country_field">country</div>
```

Because the elements were dynamically placed I can't just do this:

```
$('body').find('#billing_postcode_field').insertBefore('');
```

Comment: Think about what this code is doing. When a node is inserted in to the DOM it then inserts another 2 nodes, which raise this event again which adds another 2 nodes, which raises this event again....

Comment: I've read that I had to use the DOMNodeInserted event to move these elements because they were dynamically placed.  I've tried to remove DOMNodeInserted around my inserts but that doesn't work.

Comment: In that case please edit the question to include some context about when you expect this code to run. I'm sure there's a way to do what you require, but we need to know what that is in order to help you

Comment: Check that `this` is only what you expect it to be then return false, eg `if ($(this).is(".dynamically_added_fields_contains")) { ..make inserts..  return false; }`.  It may need a return false if `this` is the `#billing_country_field` container instead / aswell?

Comment: I cannot follow anymore. Sorry. The dynamic placed fields are always their. They only thing I need to do is, move the order of the fields.

Comment: I've tried to following:
if ($(this).is('#billing_postcode_field')) {

    //move before country fields
    $(this).find('#billing_postcode_field').insertBefore('#billing_country_field');
    $(this).find('#billing_city_field').insertAfter('#billing_postcode_field');

    return false;
   }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you wish to use the event `DOMNodeInserted`, but you can still do what you wish without:

```
(function($) {
  $("body").find('#billing_postcode_field').insertBefore('#billing_country_field');
  $("body").find('#billing_city_field').insertBefore('#billing_country_field');
})(jQuery);
```

```js
(function($) {
  $("body").find('#billing_postcode_field').insertBefore('#billing_country_field');
  $("body").find('#billing_city_field').insertBefore('#billing_country_field');
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="billing_address_1_field">add</div>
<div id="billing_country_field">country</div>
<div id="billing_postcode_field">postcode</div>
<div id="billing_city_field">city</div>
```

Comment: I've read that I had to use the DOMNodeInserted event to move these elements because they were dynamically placed. I've tested it with your code but it doesn't work. But it works when I paste your code in my console.

Comment: Then its because they are added after the code run. How are they added?

Comment: That's the issue indeed. They are also added with JS by a Wordpress plugin.